# SSH port tunnelling to access device on VPN server's network (not connected to VPN)

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, smb, ssh-tunnel

not sure if this is possible (maybe with double tunnelling?) or whether it would even be helpful. But, first, 1) let me tell you about my setup and then 2) what I want to achieve and finally 3) why I want to do that.

**1) My setup**

On my home LAN I have setup a Open VPN server running on Raspberry Pi 3. The IP address of the RP3 on the local network is 192.168.0.100. On the same LAN is also my wife's MacBook Pro with IP address 192.168.0.101.
When I create the VPN, the IP address of the VPN server is 10.8.0.1. When I connect to the VPN from outside (let's say workplace) I am assigned an IP address 10.8.0.2. If my wife connects to the VPN, she get's an IP address 10.8.0.3 I can connect to her shared drives (over SMB) at smb://10.8.0.3 (and using her login credentials).

**2) What I want to achieve**

I want to be able to connect to her shared drives without her first needing to connect to the VPN (let's say she's in a middle of network sensitive operation and VPN connection, which causes a short connection drop, would not be desirable). My reasoning is that when I connect to the VPN from the work place (at 10.8.0.1), and my VPN server can see my wife's Mac (at 192.168.0.101), isn't there a way I can access her shared drives without her needing to first connect to the VPN? In short, is it possible for the remote device with IP address 10.8.0.2 access shared drives of a Mac with IP address 192.168.0.101?

Also, I think worth considering is the fact, that SMB on Mac listens on port 445 (if I Google and read correctly).

**3) Why I want this**

- As I said, there's an advantage to no disruption in network connectivity on the Mac's side.
- Also, I'm wondering, whether transfer speeds would be any faster (or slower) this way in comparison when both are connected to the VPN. Any qualified opinion?
- Unattended access – let's say my wife is away from the computer, I don't have to ask her or TeamViewer into her Mac to enable VPN (although it could probably be started via Terminal over SSH...). But this is cleaner and easier in my mind:)

I'm wondering whether some sort of SSH port tunnelling is the solution to my "problem", but really have no idea how and where to properly set it. Any help or direction is much appreciated! So, thanks in advance for any help and/or recommendation. And if what I'm trying to do here is a complete nonsense, just tell me to drop it.